# IndoorAtlas SDK 2.0: How to resize the image using picasso?

Tags: java, android, picasso, indoor-positioning-system

Apparently, I am developing an Indoor Positioning System and I want to resize an image which is being fetched from the server using picasso library, however I am getting a null pointer exception error which says: **Attempt to read from field 'double com.indooratlas.android.sdk.resources.IALatLng.latitude' on a null object reference**.

I know why I am getting this null pointer exception, however I do not see any other approach to resize the image. 
Here is my **ImageViewActivity** named Extra_Activity which does not contain full code and only contains related code snippet:

```
public class Extra_activity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static final float dotRadius = 1.0f;
    private static final int MAX_DIMENSION = 2048;
    private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
    private IAResourceManager mResourceManager;
    private IATask<IAFloorPlan> mPendingAsyncResult;
    //private IAFloorPlan mFloorPlan;
    private BlueDotView mImageView;
    private Target mLoadTarget;
    private static final String TAG ="FloorPlanLoader";
    private IALatLng latLng;

    private IALocationListener mIALocationListener = new IALocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
            if (mImageView != null && mImageView.isReady()) {
                latLng = new IALatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                //PointF point = mFloorPlan.coordinateToPoint(latLng);
                //mImageView.setDotCenter(point);
                //mImageView.postInvalidate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
       }
    };

    private IARegion.Listener mRegionListener = new IARegion.Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEnterRegion(IARegion region) {
            if (region.getType() == IARegion.TYPE_FLOOR_PLAN) {
                String id = region.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "floorPlan changed to " + id);
                fetchFloorPlan(id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitRegion(IARegion region) {
            // leaving a previously entered region
        }
   };

   private void showFloorPlanImage(final IAFloorPlan floorPlan) {
        final String filePath = floorPlan.getUrl();
        if (mLoadTarget == null)
        {
            mLoadTarget = new Target()
            {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBitmap loaded with dimensions: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x"
                            + bitmap.getHeight());
                    mImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true)));
                    mImageView.setRadius(floorPlan.getMetersToPixels() * dotRadius);
                    PointF point = floorPlan.coordinateToPoint(latLng);
                    mImageView.setDotCenter(point);
                    mImageView.postInvalidate();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    Toast.makeText(Extra_activity.this, "Failed to load bitmap",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
        }
        RequestCreator request = Picasso.with(this).load(filePath).rotate(90); //.resize(0,0)
        final int bitmapWidth = floorPlan.getBitmapWidth();
        final int bitmapHeight = floorPlan.getBitmapHeight();
        if (bitmapHeight > MAX_DIMENSION) {
            request.resize(0, MAX_DIMENSION);
        } else if (bitmapWidth > MAX_DIMENSION) {
            request.resize(MAX_DIMENSION, 0);
        }
        request.into(mLoadTarget);
        Log.w(TAG, "showFloorPlanImage: " + filePath);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void fetchFloorPlan(String id) {
        cancelPendingNetworkCalls();
        final IATask<IAFloorPlan> asyncResult = mResourceManager.fetchFloorPlanWithId(id);
        mPendingAsyncResult = asyncResult;
        if (mPendingAsyncResult != null) {
            mPendingAsyncResult.setCallback(new IAResultCallback<IAFloorPlan>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(IAResult<IAFloorPlan> result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "fetch floor plan result:" + result);
                    if (result.isSuccess() && result.getResult() != null)
                    {
                        //mFloorPlan = result.getResult();
                        showFloorPlanImage(result.getResult());
                    } else {
                        if (!asyncResult.isCancelled()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Extra_activity.this,
                                    (result.getError() != null
                                            ? "error loading floor plan: " + result.getError()
                                            : "access to floor plan denied"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
    }

    private void cancelPendingNetworkCalls() {
        if (mPendingAsyncResult != null && !mPendingAsyncResult.isCancelled()) {
            mPendingAsyncResult.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

The error message from logcat:

[image: NullPointerException]

The **(Extra_activity.java:154)** refers to **PointF point = floorPlan.coordinateToPoint(latLng);** in the **showFloorPlanImage** method. The **PointF point = floorPlan.coordinateToPoint(latLng);** should be placed in the onLocationChanged method however, in this code snippet I can't use **PointF point = floorPlan.coordinateToPoint(latLng);** inside that method as variable **floorplan** can only be accessed inside **showFloorPlanImage** method. And this whole leads to null pointer exception.

I have asked a similar question to this one where I used a different approach (different code), however, I was able to resize the image but the blue dot was getting displayed out of sight: "[IndoorAtlas SDK 2.0: Using Picasso with custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708350/indooratlas-sdk-2-0-using-picasso-with-custom-imageview)"

What is the correct solution as none of my approaches seems to work? Many thanks in advance if you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the relation between your Nullpointer and the image resizing. However what you want to achieve here is only resizing an image if I understand it right. Instead of trying to resize the image itself, why don't you resize its container instead? (here the `ImageView`). You can achieve that with `getLayoutParams().height` and `getLayoutParams().width` or in xml like in this example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: (1) The image is not stored or placed in the drawable folder nor it can be placed at all as the image is coming from the server. (2) The image is being displayed in a custom view. You can go to the link which I have provided to view the custom imageview class. (3) I have tried resizing custom view just like your solution however, it doesn't work as no matter what the container size is, the image always will be displayed to its original width and height, and, as a result, I have to resize the image programmatically, the only way is to use Target interface. I tried layoutparams, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from incomplete code snippets, but to me it looks like your error is unrelated to either Picasso or IndoorAtlas. You seem to have used [our example code](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/imageview/ImageViewActivity.java) as a template, but made `latLng` an instance variable.
As a consequence, your `onBitmapLoaded()` where you get the NPE can be called (and apparently is called) before `latLng` is initialized. The latter happens asynchronously at the `onLocationChanged()` callback (and in this case, after you needed it). You can't depend on a particular calling order when working with asynchronous callback constructs.

Best of luck in your development!

Comment: I understand and I know that the error is unrelated to IndoorAtlas, however, as you know that I have used your code template, I am looking for someone who have used your code template and has successfully resized the image and maybe could help me with finding the correct approach. And that is why in the title, I mentioned IndoorAtlas. I will take your feedback into account and will try to make changes in my code.